# How to solve a specific exponential equation where the power of the exponential function is a function of the variable to be solved

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve "x" in the following exponential equations
(1) A = x Exp[(m/x)+n x]
(2) B = x Exp[(m/x)+x^n]
where A, B, m and n are constants.
I could easily solve A = x Exp[(m/x)]  (the codes are given below).
`Solve[x Exp[m/x] - A == 0, x] {{x -> -(m/ProductLog[-(m/A)])}}`

But error occurs when I try to solve the equations (1) and (2)(The codes are given below). Kindly help me out. I will be very grateful.
`Solve[x Exp[m/x + n x] - A == 0, x]`
On giving this command for the first equation it says "Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve."
Similarly for equation (2) on giving command
`Solve[x Exp[m/x + x^n] - B == 0, x]` it shows the same way.

Comment: Equations (1) and (2)  are two seperate equations and have nothing to do with each other. We have to solve 'x' for both the equations separately. A, B, m and n are arbitrary constants and can take any value. I am updating the question where the code is given where I'am getting the error.

Comment: There is no any specific value for A, B, m and n. We need a generalised solution for 'x'.

Comment: We too know that and that's why we specified it already in the question. It will be helpful even if you show how to solve it for n=1.

Comment: How about focus on just the first and consider if Mathematica can determine under what conditions on the values of A,n,m does it have a real solution?  For example $1000=x e^{3/x+4x}$ has a solution whereas $1=xe^{3/x+4 x}$ does not have a solution.